# Suppressing headers and footers

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I suppress headers and footers on all pages after Pg. 1 in Word 2013?

Multiple places on line say to check the "different first page" box. But when I do that, the headers and footers ALL disappear.

Right now my 4 pp document has the same header and footer as P. 1.  I can either have the header/footer on all pages or none.

Comment: Insert a section break after page 1 instead of a page break. Then delete the header and footer from the 2nd section.

Comment: Shouldn't need section break to achieve this.  Before you tick the "different first page" box, select your header and cut it.  Then tick the box, and on your first page header paste the header back in.

Answer (score 1):

By checking the Different First Page box in Header and Footer Tools, you are indicating that you are changing the Header/Footer for the first page.

I suggest that after you select the option, cut the header information from the second page and paste it to the first page. This will move the header from page two to page one.

Similarly, jump to footers and perform same action.

Most documents normally have the same Header/Footer information and then the author decides to change headings on the first page. So to have Header/Footer on page 1 and suppressed thereafter, simply **cut/paste** (as opposed to copy/paste) from page the two headings.